# How to translate "stretch goals" to Esperanto?

Tags: translation

During a crowdfunding campaign, after you've received the funding you've requested, you can add additional features to a project, which will only be done if a certain amount is pledged more than the original goal. For example, in the Amikumu Kickstarter campaign, we plan to have the following stretch goals:

€13,000 Events
€16,000 Local groups (recurring events)
...

But, the problem is, how should we call these in Esperanto? We originally thought this should be *streĉaj celoj*, but a couple of people have already complained that that's too literal and doesn't really mean the same thing. Another suggestion was *perspektivaj celoj*. Other ideas?

Comment: Something along the lines of 'continuation goal'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [suggestions from johmue](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/a/1279/13) seem good, but I think the English word has a feeling that if we work really hard we might be able to acheive these goals but it isn't expected, and that isn't captured in *aldonaj celoj*. I suggest maybe *strebaj celoj* which has the feeling that if we *strebas* for the goals we might acheive them. Another idea might be to use *revaj celoj* to capture the idea they are desired but unlikely goals. We could even make a combination with *strebrevaj celoj*.

Comment: _Strebi_ is a good word here ("if we work hard"): _strebceloj, alstrebindaj celoj_, _alstrebata celo_. What about _plusceloj_?

Answer (score 9):

If these goals are defined as an addon to the original goal if the funding is given I would simply call them *aldonaj celoj*, *kromceloj*, *pliaj celoj*.

There's another definition of stretch goals, that I am aware of. This is the definition of vague (stretchable) goals which can be interpreted according to what actually has been achieved in the end. These I would call *fleksaj celoj* or colloquial *gumaj celoj*.

EDIT: Or how about *bisaj celoj* or *bisceloj*?

Answer (score 5):

I would write

> *preteraj celoj* or *preterceloj*

but you might prefer

> *superaj celoj* or *superceloj*

Answer (score -1):

What about *dauxrigaj celoj* or *dauxrigceloj*?

Comment: Welcome to _Esperanto Language_! May you explain why you think it is the correct translation?